# Auto Login for Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch, script

I have many laptops with the same image of Windows 10 on them. They are out with my students, I want to create a file that I can send them that will automatically log them into an admin account. But, i do not want to send them the username and password. I want to create a self-executing file that will automatically y log them in as the admin user.

Comment: Have you tried the run command and typing in netplwiz and uncheck the "users must enter username and password" option?

Comment: @RicardoBohner - same as the now-deleted answer. no good cos you'd have to tell the student what details to enter, negating the whole point. I don't actually think this can be done, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong :)

Comment: It's probably possible with powershell and using an encryped password but I don't know how to do it since I'm a beginner in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an encryped password with PS command, the following link might be helpful:
https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/encrypt-password-powershell/

Or you can try to configure your computer to be able to automatically log into as an admin account without typing the username and password. And then let your students to use RDP to remotelly connect it.
Please refer to for more detailed information:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows